# Coronavirus designation

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tag-renaming

The International Committee on Taxonomy of Viruses [has designated](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.02.07.937862v1) the novel coronavirus first detected in Wuhan as *SARS-CoV-2*, replacing its working designation of *2019-nCoV*. The related respiratory disease is designated *COVID-19* as announced by the WHO; I could not locate the statement on the WHO's English website, but it has been [Tweeted](https://twitter.com/WHO/status/1227248333871173632?s=20) from @WHO and is being [widely reported](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-51466362) elsewhere.

Since the older designation is now deprecated, I suggest we rename the tag  [coronavirus-2019-ncov](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coronavirus-2019-ncov) to [sars-cov-2-virus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sars-cov-2-virus) or some such.

The naming of diseases and their agents is fraught due to the dangers of stigma and panic, and because misinformation spreads so quickly. The news media's careless use of *coronavirus* has led to various conspiracy-oriented posts appearing on my social media feeds; the term applies to a whole family of viruses, and past incidents and research related to coronaviruses in general are being misapplied to the current outbreak. Thus, in my opinion I think we should avoid the term "coronavirus" in the tag name altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done! Renamed the tag to [sars-cov-2-virus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sars-cov-2-virus) to make it more scientific.

Comment: Why the virus suffix?

Comment: @noreputationplz because otherwise most people have no idea what it is

Answer (score 1):

I support it. No one calls SARS "coronavirus SARS".

I don't think there's any [sars-cov-2-bacteria](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sars-cov-2-bacteria) so [sars-cov-2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sars-cov-2) is enough.